# Linear sort by swapping adjacent numbers

Tags: python

I've been trying to accomplish a simple linear sort that will, in this case, make a swap at every index except for when it reaches the end. Kindly help. (the while loop might be unnecessary at this point)

```
array = list(range(9, -1, -1))

has_flipped = True

while has_flipped:

    for num in array:

        if array.index(num) == (len(array) - 1):
            continue

        if num > array[array.index(num) + 1]:
            container = array[array.index(num) + 1]
            array[array.index(num) + 1] = num
            num = container
            has_flipped = False

    has_flipped = not has_flipped
```

I expect a list with the numbers 0 through 9 but I instead get 9, 9, 7, 7, 5, 5, 3, 3, 1, 1.

Answer (score 0):

You do not swap rightly. You never assign to array locations in right manner. As the other answerer explains...

```
num = container
```

...does not assign to an array location.

Moreover, the `while` loop is not required. Here is a more compact way of doing the same:

```
array = list(range(9, -1, -1))

ln = len(array)

for num in array:
    if num > array[ln-1]:
        container = array[ln-1]
        array[ln-1] = num
        array[array.index(num)] = container
    ln -= 1

print(array)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```